# Calling upon a single, specific row from core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a bunch of MySQL rows that I downloaded to iOS from a PHP script and saved into core-data. Now, I am relatively new to core-data. How would I go about obtaining one of those rows from core-data to display? If that was too vague, here is my situation: when a user clicks on a specific button in iOS, I would like to display a specific result based on the user such as the name for a city that matched a user location from a bigger list of city names. However, I just would need one row. I am merely hoping to understand the process and any help, whether it be tutorials or specific suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Although CoreData can use a database for storage, it is not in and of itself a database. Thinking in terms of rows is only going to cause you trouble. What you really need to do is fetch an object. Please read the core data programming guide on the Apple dev site.

Comment: Yes, but couldn't it be used as a temporary storage (for about a minute or so)...I simply need to store user data from my server and display specific information. Then it can go ahead and delete everything except what was displayed until they repeat. Would this fall under another category, or does coredata use other resources for even temporary storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the basics to work with objects:

```
// Utility method to fetch objects
    - (NSArray *)fetchEntity:(NSString *)entityName  withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc
    {
        NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];    
        NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        [request setEntity:entity];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];

        return  [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    }
```

You can use it like this to get the name:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",@"My product"]; // act as a filter
NSManagedObject *product = [[CoreDataUtils fetchEntity:@"Product" withPredicate:predicate inContext:self.moc] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",[product objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

Or you can set the name like this:

```
[product setValue:@"New Product" forKey:@"name"];
```

Dont forget to save your NSManagedObjectContext when you edit your object

```
[self managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Theres a great tutorial here: [Core Data on iOS 5 Tutorial: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Thanks! This really was informative!